# Calling a method adding input

Tags: java, class, methods, input, output

I'm having problems finding out how to get the output based on the user inputs for my Main class. I already have keyboard entry where the users can enter a value, which will be held. I'm guessing I will need to use that e.g. **(input.input1());**. However I also need to include the method which calculates the result e.g **calculations.theAverageMassFfTheVehicle** from the CalculatingRocketFlightProfile class,  I'm just not sure how to combine the two to get the result.

//Calculations class

```
public class CalculatingRocketFlightProfile { //Calculation class

//Declaring fields
public double totalImpulse ;
public double averageImpulse;
public double timeEjectionChargeFires;
public double massEmptyVehicle;
public double engineMass;
public double fuelMass; 
//Declaring variables for outputs
public double theAverageMassOfTheVehicle;
public double theVehiclesMaximumVelocity;

public CalculatingRocketFlightProfile(double totalImpulse, double averageImpulse, double timeEjectionChargeFires, double massEmptyVehicle,
                                  double engineMass, double fuelMass) { //Constructor for this class

                        this.totalImpulse  = totalImpulse;
                        this.averageImpulse = averageImpulse;
                        this.timeEjectionChargeFires = timeEjectionChargeFires;
                        this.massEmptyVehicle = massEmptyVehicle;
                        this.engineMass = engineMass;
                        this.fuelMass = fuelMass;
                    }


//Mutators and Accessors

//Accessors
//Methods for calculations - Calculating outputs, using inputs. 

public double theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() {
    return massEmptyVehicle + ((engineMass + (engineMass - fuelMass) )/ 2);  //Formula to calculate Average mass 
}//method

public double theVehiclesMaximumVelocity() { //Formula to calculate Maximum velocity
    return totalImpulse / getTheAverageMassOfTheVehicle();
}//method



//Returns - GET
public double getTheAverageMassOfTheVehicle() {
    return theAverageMassOfTheVehicle;
}//method

public double getTheVehiclesMaximumVelocity() {
    return theVehiclesMaximumVelocity;
}//method

}//class
```

//Main class

```
public class Main { //Master class


        public static void main( String args[] ) //Standard header for main method
        {



        kbentry input = new kbentry();

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Total Impulse: " );
        System.out.println("You have entered : " +input.input1());


        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Average Impulse: " );
        System.out.println("You have entered : " +input.input2());

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Time ejection charge fires: " );
        System.out.println("You have entered : " +input.input3());

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the vehicle: " );
        System.out.println("You have entered : " +input.input4());

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the engine: " );
        System.out.println("You have entered : " +input.input5());

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for the Mass of the fuel: " );
        System.out.println("You have entered : " +input.input6());

        //Output

        CalculatingRocketFlightProfile calculations = new CalculatingRocketFlightProfile();


        System.out.println("\nThe average mass of the vehicle: " +calculations.theAverageMassOfTheVehicle() +
                           "\nThe vehicles maximum velocity: " + calculations.theVehiclesMaximumVelocity());

        }
        }
```

//kbentry

```
public class kbentry{

double input1(){

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

//Total Impulse entry
String strTotalImpulse = null;  // These must be initialised
int    intTotalImpulse = 0;

//System.out.print("Please enter a number for Total Impulse: ");
//System.out.flush();

// read string value from keyboard
try {
  strTotalImpulse = in.readLine();
} 
catch (IOException ioe) { 
  // ignore exception
       }

// convert it to integer
try {
  intTotalImpulse = Integer.parseInt(strTotalImpulse);
} 
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
   System.out.println("Error! Please enter a number!" + nfe.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're CalcultingRocketFlightProfile class needs parameters, but you're creating calculations without passing any parameters to the new CalcultingRocketFlightProfile.

You should store those inputs in variables, then pass those variables to the constructor in your new CalcultingRocketFlightProfile that you declare.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show what you mean? I'm really new to programming.

Comment: Constructors allow you to pass parameters to your class. Simply include public YourClassName (var A, var B, etc) {var1 = A, var2 = A, etc.} substituting the variable names and data types according to your class. You can pass the parameters when creating it similar to how you'd pass parameters to a method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off you are not actually passing any of your input to the Calculations class.  I am not sure what input.input1() is or if you have an input class that you did not post. Either way you can do this a couple different ways.

1. First off give your input variables a meaningful name so you know which ones you are dealing with.  Then pass all of your input.

   CalculatingRocketFlightProfile calculations = new CalculatingRocketFlightProfile(input1, input2, etc..)

or

Place all your input variables into your calculations class. Then store user input as calculations.totalImpulse, etc...  Then you call your calculation methods to display answers.

-EDIT-

Just have 2 classes, your main and calculations class. There is no need for another class just to handle keyboard input.

Example

Main class

```
public class Main { 

    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

        CalculatingRocketFlightProfile calculations = new CalculatingRocketFlightProfile();

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number for Total Impulse: " );
        calculations.totalImpulse = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
        System.out.println("You have entered : " + calculations.totalImpulse);
    }
}

public class CalculatingRocketFlightProfile { //Calculation class

//Declaring fields
public double totalImpulse ;

// Do all of your maths, and methods for answer return
}
```

You were not actually taking the keyboard input and assigning it to anything.  Using a scanner object you can assign the input to a variable in your calculations class.  If you do that for all of them, you dont actually need a constructor in your calculations class, you just use it to do all that math and return answers.

Comment: Yes I have a keyboard entry class where I have the methods for the inputs. e.g. input1, input2 etc...

I'm a a bit confused by what you mean, could you please provide the code so I can see what is going on? Thanks

Comment: In my assignment I must use a seperate keyboard entry class, where I declare methods; input1, input2, input3 etc...because it has to do exception handling as well. Is there a way to do it using the main class I have originally posted?

Comment: You can do it wherever you want to.  But you have to have a object that reads the input (such as a Scanner object), then you have to pass the variable to the keyboard entry class.  Then pass them to the calculations class.

Comment: Just on a side note, for your future reference, you are not required to put keyboard input in a separate class for exception handling.  You can surround input in a try-catch anywhere.  You are doing it to show that you can pass variables from one class to another. Take a look at this tutorial on classes [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having issues. The reason why my kbentry input = kbentry() object is created is to hold the user input values. my kbentry class holds the exception handling and reads the input. I have updated my code to show this. How can I pass variables to it?

Comment: Ok, does your main class have to have the console output requesting the input or can you move it to the kbentry class and just call a method in your main?